# Can't send the funds - encryption password forgotten. Copay

Tags: copay

I know my 12 word phrase but can't remember the encryption password. What is the procedure to recover the wallet? How many times can I insert the encryption password wrong before my account gets blocked? I've got several passwords which I'd like to test.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the app, choose "import wallet", and you're fine. This procedure applies to all wallets with seeds. There are no limits, remember that Bitcoin's motto is "Be your own bank"

Or, just look for the "import wallet" button.

Comment: I believe some wallets with seeds can require a ["seed extension", "extension word" or "13th/25th word"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase#Two-Factor_Seed_Phrases) for recovery. Someone might describe this as an "encryption password" because that is how it is used.

Comment: As @redgrittybrick notes, if this is actually a seed extension/passphrase, then you will need your "encryption password" to access your wallet - and hence your bitcoins.